# Is there a way to put my Tkinter text box inserts on different lines?

Tags: python, string, tkinter, text, box

The text box puts the `“___searching___”` output all on one line, how do you make this into different lines?

```py
 def movie_print(root,entry,count):
    T = Text(root, height = 5, width = 52)
    T.place(x=250,y=180)
  
    #for loop that loops through every movie relating to that search
    for movie in movies[0:5]: #only loops 5 timed
      
      #outputs a spacer on the tkinter window
      spacer = "___Searching___"
      T.insert(tk.END, spacer)
```

Comment: Add `\n` at the end of `spacer`: `spacer = "___Searching___\n"`.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Removed line 11. Just add another `'\n'` in line 10.

```
def movie_print(root,entry,count):
    T = Text(root, height = 5, width = 52)
    T.place(x=250,y=180)
  
    #for loop that loops through every movie relating to that search
    for movie in movies[0:5]: #only loops 5 timed
      
      #outputs a spacer on the tkinter window
      spacer = "___Searching___"
      T.insert(tk.END, spacer + '\n')
```